# Bootstrap flex direction - row and column -

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

As you know, bootstrap is running according to the class value of the parents for (flex row/column).

```css
.bd-highlight {
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

I want to use an exception in row: Like at `self-column`

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight self-column">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

I produced a solution like this but not work:

```css
.bd-highlight {
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight w-100">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

I do not know what I'm doing, but is there a special and right class I can add to my library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to activate the wrap by adding `flex-wrap`:

```css
.bd-highlight {
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight w-100">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```